# Models and standard scores

Tags: r, regression, linear-model, z-score

I'd like to use standard scores to describe a variable $y$. If I always measured $y$ in a particular place and time, I'd just take the mean and standard deviation of $y$ and then calculate the standard score for $y_i$ like so: $z_i = \frac{y_i - \mu}{\sigma}$.

Let's say that $y(x)$, though, like in the example below.

```r
# Set RNG seed
set.seed(33550336)

# Create toy data frame
df <- data.frame(x = runif(1000, 0, 100))
df$y <- with(df, 10 * x + 3 + rnorm(length(x), 0, 100))

# Plot data
with(df, plot(x, y))

# Fit model to synthetic data
mod_fit <- lm(y ~ x, data = df) 

# Plot model
lines(0:100, predict(mod_fit, data.frame(x = 0:100)), col = "red", lwd = 5)
```

[image]

If I just used the mean and standard deviation across all of $x$ to calculate $z_i$, it would be skewed by where (i.e., at which $x$) I observed $y_i$. To get around this, I fit a linear model which gives an expected value for $y(x)$, shown as the red line in the plot. I can then calculate the difference between $y_i$ and the model and this would account for the fact that $y(x)$.

```r
# Add model predicted value to data frame
df$y_p <- predict(mod_fit)

# Calculate deviation
df$anom <- df$y - df$y_p

# Look at results
head(df)
#>          x          y       y_p       anom
#> 1 86.36470 849.751977 869.06456  -19.31258
#> 2 35.22257 450.308201 353.37350   96.93470
#> 3 52.57408 419.659783 528.33726 -108.67747
#> 4  6.67227  -9.700307  65.48683  -75.18714
#> 5 37.51383 419.145838 376.47735   42.66849
#> 6 91.97086 770.256306 925.59425 -155.33794
```

<sup>Created on 2019-01-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

This makes sense to me: a positive value would mean the observation is above average for that particular location (i.e., $x$). What baffles me is how to calculate the standard deviation with which to normalise the difference between model and observation. If I took the standard deviation over all of $x$, this is based on the mean over all of $x$. Presumably, the standard deviation should be constant over $x$ if observations are homoscedastic, but how do I calculate it?

---

#### Edit

Do I use the standard deviation of $y_i$ minus the model?

Comment: Standardized residuals, studentized residuals, mean squared error of regression - these are some terms you should want to read about. On this site as well.

Comment: @ttnphns Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. It sounds like studentized residuals are close to what I need, but the form of the denominator [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Studentized_residual#Calculation) looks a bit weird to me. When used in their usual context, scaling the standard deviation in the denominator makes sense, but I wonder if in my context it would remove vital information. In short, would it attenuate the magnitude of those points far from the model, when what I actually want is a "standardised" measure of how far points are from the model?

Comment: Studentized residuals are a minor modification of standardized residuals to make them more resemble true (populational) _errors_. $h$ in denominator are "leverages". Leverages reflect the fact that in a sample, strongly deviated observations (especially such as outliers) on X variable are more influential. Leverages just reflect the deviation. If in your sample you don't mind that extreme X observations are somewhat more influential, just use standardized residuals.